# How to internationalize a Hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, internationalization

I'm trying to add internationalization (multiple languages) support to java entities. I'm open to any options with as few boilerplate code as possible when adding translation to each new field. I am not limited to JPA, can use hibernate annotations as well. In worst case plain sql will suit as well. Possibly there are some ready libraries that I haven't found. **It should not necessary follow my idea described below.**

Ideally I need the database to look like this:

```
i18n
+------+--------+------+
|  id  | locale | text |
+------+--------+------+
|  1   |   en   | foo  |
+------+--------+------+
|  1   |   de   | bar  |
+------+--------+------+
|  2   |   en   | foo2 |
+------+--------+------+
|  2   |   de   | bar2 |
+------+--------+------+

parent
+------+------+
|  id  | text |
+------+------+
|  99  |   1  |
+------+------+
|  100 |   2  |
+------+------+
```

`i18n` is a table that should contain just 3 columns: `id`, `locale` and `text`. Table `parent` has a column `text` (if there is just single field that requires i18n, more columns otherwise) that contains values from `i18n.id`. I tried the following mapping in the Parent class:

```
@ElementCollection @CollectionTable(name="i18n", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name="locale") @Column(name="text")
public Map<String, String> text = newHashMap();
```

It seems to work when DDL generation is disabled and I create tables by myself, but when DDL generation is enabled, it generates an unnecessary column `i18n.parent_id` and a constraint for it:

```
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.I18N ADD CONSTRAINT 
PUBLIC.FK_HVGN9UJ4DJOFGLT8L78BYQ75I FOREIGN KEY(PARENT_ID) INDEX 
PUBLIC.FK_HVGN9UJ4DJOFGLT8L78BYQ75I_INDEX_2 REFERENCES 
PUBLIC.PARENT(ID) NOCHECK
```

How can I get rid of this extra column? Is it possible to avoid having a reference from `i18n` table to `parent` table? This link makes it difficult to reuse the `i18n` table. I either need to hold some discriminator value in `i18n` table or use GUID throughout the database, as id's in different tables will clash. First option means lots of boilerplate code. Second option means a lot of work to be done in the current project.

I need a reusable way to add i18n to entity. My parent classes will look approximately like this. And there will be several such parent classes with **different set of fields** that must be internationalized.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String title; // must be in internationalized
    public String text; // must be in internationalized
    public String details; // must be in internationalized

    // ... other fields
}
```

Comment: What is unneccessary about the parent_id field?  Your element collection needs some way to associate the rows within the generated table to the parent entity - a foreign key.  Maybe show how you want the database to look, and someone can help you figure out how to map entities to it.

Comment: I added desired database description. I need a reusable i18n table for one-to-many relationship from parent. I need to be able to use the same i18n table to store translations for other fields. Parent.text & i18n.id should be the way to associate the rows within the generated table to the parent entity. Foreign key constraint may exist only on parent.text.

Comment: Can you show the full `i18n` class?

Comment: There is no i18n class. @ElementCollection doesn't need to it.

Comment: MapkeyColumn isn't what you thought it was, as the map key is something unique to key values on.  You might use a map key of 'locale', creating a map of text keyed on the locale.  What is the problem if your i18n table just uses the ID value, 99 instead of adding a new arbitrary 'text' field?   These texts aren't meant to be shared amongst entities, are they?  If they are to be reused, you really should make them entities, using id+locale as a composite pk.  JPA doesn't allow using a partial value for the foreign key, but Hibernate and other providers might have a way to map 'text' -> id.

Comment: If i18n table keeps ids of parent (e.g. 99), then I need to either keep a separate i18n table for each field, or have a GUID as a parent id, or add a discriminator value to i18n table to store a unique name of each parent field. I don't like all 3 options. My current database structure looks optimal to me and I just need to come up with a list of annotations to map it. I am surprised that it is so complicated. If you know how to do this with requested database structure, then please add an answer with concrete set of annotations and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

> On the database level collection instances are distinguished by the foreign key of the entity that owns the collection. This foreign key is referred to as the collection key column, or columns, of the collection table.

So I suppose you want to disable the forgien key generation for your propose, simplely you can do it with this

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "i18n", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none"), joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "locale")
    @Column(name = "text")
    public Map<String, String> text = new HashMap<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(Map<String, String> text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Then when you verify the generated DDL, the forgien key it not applyed to the I18N table, but still get the ability

```
@Test
public void testParent() {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    HashMap<String, String> text = new HashMap<>();
    text.put("en", "foo");
    text.put("de", "bar");
    p.setText(text);

    entityManager.persist(p);
    entityManager.flush();

    Parent parent = entityManager.find(Parent.class, p.getId());
    System.out.println("en: " + parent.getText().get("en"));
    System.out.println("de: " + parent.getText().get("de"));
}
```

About is a simple test( Spring Boot 1.4 release ), and will see the output in the console:

```
Hibernate: 
    create table i18n (
        id bigint not null,
        text varchar(255),
        locale varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (id, locale)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table parent (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        primary key (id)
    ) 
......
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        parent
        (id) 
    values
        (null)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        i18n
        (id, locale, text) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        i18n
        (id, locale, text) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
en: foo
de: bar
```

This is the table in H2 db:

[image]

Comment: In your solution `parent` table has only `id` field, there is no other field to keep a link to `i18n` table. Seems that in test you get all values from `i18n` table assigned to `text` map, therefore it works. Probably you made a link from `i18n.id` to `parent.id` and both are nulls. It is not a working solution.

Comment: @user1603038 you can check the DDL, there is no any link in `parent` `i18n` table, the relationship should be ketp by the literal value of `parent.id` and `i18n.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Hibernate does not provide any `i18n` support out of the box, so you on the right way to implement custom solution for this.
I can also assume that your goal is to add localization support to an existing project with minimal cost.

I can suggest you to use `ManyToMany` relation on `Parent` and `i18n` tables.

In this case you are fully independent on `Parent` and `i18n` tables structure as you want, but there is some overhead with additional join tables per each `"Parent"`, which contains PK reference pairs form `i18n` and `"Parent"` table. Also with `ManyToMany` approach records form `i18n` can be reused in different `"Parent"` tables.

So your table structure may look like this:

```
i18n
+------+--------+------+
|  id  | locale | text |
+------+--------+------+
|  1   |   en   | foo  |
+------+--------+------+
|  2   |   de   | bar  |
+------+--------+------+
|  3   |   en   | foo2 |
+------+--------+------+
|  4   |   de   | bar2 |
+------+--------+------+

i18n_parent
+-------------+---------+
|   text_id   | i18n_id |
+-------------+---------+
|      1      |   1     |
+------+------+---------+
|      1      |   2     |
+------+------+---------+
|      2      |   3     |
+------+------+---------+
|      2      |   4     |
+------+------+---------+


parent
+------+------+
|  id  | text |
+------+------+
|  99  |   1  |
+------+------+
|  100 |   2  |
+------+------+
```

Entity code example:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "i18n_parent",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "text_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "i18n_id"))
    @MapKey(name = "locale")
    private Map<String, LocalizedTextEntity> text = new HashMap<>();

    .....    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "i18n")
public class LocalizedTextEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "locale")
    private String locale;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like you are searching for hibernate composite primary key. You should perform this trick:

```
@Embeddable
public class LocaleForeignKey {
    Integer id;
    String locale;
}

@Entity
public class I18n {
    @AttributeOverrides({
      @AttributeOverride(name="id", column = @Column(name="id"))
      @AttributeOverride(name="locale", column = @Column(name="locale"))
    })
    @EmbeddedId
    LocaleForeignKey id;

    String text;
    ...getters-setters
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to map it as 'locale' map, but think it possible with @JoinColumn annotations, or try to follow to @Alan Hay post.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just specifying the `@JoinColumn` incorrectly by using

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id"))
```

rather than

```
@JoinColumn(name="id"))
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName()

> When used in a CollectionTable mapping, **the referenced column is in
>   the table of the entity containing the collection**

So, essentially you are (re)defining the ID column in parent and Hibernate is generating the FK column in i18n using its default naming strategy.

Using this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "i18n", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ii8n_to_parent_fk"), joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "locale")
    @Column(name = "text")
    public Map<String, String> text = new HashMap<>();

}
```

generates the following:

```
19:29:08.890 [main] DEBUG jdbc.sqlonly -  org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
3. create table i18n (id bigint not null, text varchar(255), locale varchar(255) not null, primary 
key (id, locale)) 

19:29:09.464 [main] DEBUG jdbc.sqlonly -  org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
3. alter table i18n add constraint ii8n_to_parent_fk foreign key (id) references parent
```

Comment: foreign key (id) references parent - this means that i18n.id must contain only parent.id values, but it's not what I need. I need a foreign key on parent.text to contain only i18n.id values.

Comment: Can you post your full entity class Parent then to explain how **exactly** you see that working? You've got a 250 bounty on offer and zero answers. What does that tell you?

Comment: I added an example of the parent class and updated the question a bit, however I need a generic solution that doesn't depend on a parent class structure.